# What's the problem with my gain block?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, control-system, kicad

I'm trying to amplify my output using a non-inverting amp as a gain block but it messes up the output.

Here's my circuit:
[image]

Vout before connecting to the gain block:

[image]

Vout after connecting to the gain block:
[image]

I don't understand why i'm not getting the same smooth response without the gain block. I've rechecked my OP AMP pins to make sure everything is wired up correctly. Im at my wits end at this one.

Here is my full circuit with the gain block.
[image]

Also, could anyone explain why my output is decreasing instead of increasing?

Comment: I will give you the advise I give all beginners that immediately start with a transient simulation: start with an **operating point** (.op) simulation and check that all DC voltages are what they need to be. If you're lucky the simulator can annotate those DC voltages into the schematic. If the DC voltages are all OK then indeed Simon's suggestion about the capacitor is a good one.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm sorry but I can't find any info about an .op simulation in kiCad .

Comment: I looked in the manuals and indeed, KiCad doesn't have this (yet). Or more accurate: it is not dierctly available to the user. Because there is an AC analysis and if that works with transistors then you cannot do a meaningful AC without doing a DC operating point first. Sometimes a DC sweep can be faked/misused to do the same though. I don't use KiCad (anymore, never used it for simulation) so I cannot tell you how to do this.

Comment: I see. Thank you anyway for checking @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: @Duts - You just reversed (rolledback) an edit which fixed your question, to make your images visible again. Are you trying to remove your images? That would not be allowed, as they are required in order to make sense of your question. So please (quickly) explain why you seem to be trying to remove the images from your question, and even removed them again when others kindly put them back. Thanks.

Comment: @Duts - Hi, After further review of your actions, it's now clear that you have been deliberately removing the images from your question. As I said, that is not allowed, as they are required in order to understand the question - removing them is effectively vandalism, as the answer(s) then don't make sense. Therefore I am reverting to your original version of the question, with the images visible, and locking the question to prevent further edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is the 940F capacitor, with a time constant of about 600s in combination with the 0.61Ω resistor.

What you are seeing here is a very very slow charging capacitor - check out the x axis units of kiloseconds!

Did you mean picofarads, or nanofarads?

Since the capacitor really is that large (which is ridiculous), then what you are seeing *is* the DC operating point, that ngspice (used by Kicad) has calculated.

The entire range in the first graph is only 30nV, and in the second graph the y-axis spans only tens of picovolts. This tiny little charge curve is meaningless on such small scales.

You probably should ask ngspice to "skip initial operating point solution", using the UIC argument, with a command like this:

```
.tran 100m 5000 0.2 UIC
```

When spice, or ngspice performs a transient analysis, it will first calculate all quiescent values by setting all capcitances and inductances to zero, which reveals the state of the circuit if left for an infinitely long time, the so-called "DC operating point, or "quiescent state". Transient analysis proper begins from that state.

By disabling that initial quiescent solution, transient analysis takes place as if power is suddenly applied, without first giving the circuit "time to settle". You should be able to see the state evolve from power-on, as you would on an oscilloscope, such as the charging voltage curve of a capacitor charging to its DC operating point.

Comment: Its really 940F. Our professor was the one who chose the RC value

Comment: I was actually also thinking of setting IC=0 at first but didn't know how to implement it in kicad. Thank you very much! It's actually worked.

Comment: Do relay to your professor that 940 F isn't a realistic capacitor and that it is "silly" to confuse your students with such large values. Only if the 940 F models something else could that value make sense.

Comment: We were surprised as well with the values. Definitely was confusing.

Comment: Yes when Rb/Rc   is >>> hFE you know somethings wrong with the design

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I never even noticed that! I'm getting long in the tooth.

Comment: @SimonFitch I wouldn't advise using `uic` and, instead, rely on the simulator's detection of the operating point, since OP needs the steady-state analysis (by the looks of it). Otherwise -- in particular for this case -- there should be 3000 s of wating for the .op to be reached.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You might be right, though from the question I assumed he was looking for the exponential curve. I simply showed him how to see it.

Comment: @SimonFitch There's always the possibility that I, too, misunderstood, that's why I used the cautious "wouldn't". Also the fact that the .op may not always be the correct one. Maybe it would have been better "use `uic` only if you know what you are doing, otherwise trust the simulator".

Comment: Still, I don't see the problem in OP, since the Y axes show the values for a virtual steady-state.